# How to change the current brace color in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

How can I change the color of the braces that are circled below? When the cursor is positioned inside the color changes to black.

I have tried the Brace Matching (Rectangle) setting - but that appears to only be valid when your cursor is on the actual brace.

[image: Current Bracket Color]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this: braces from the current scope are not highlighted. They keep the default operator style. How did you enable this?

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I'm using a theme [link](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian). However resetting the UI settings via Tools - Import / Export Settings does not stop this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't highlight braces from the current scope. You are probably using an extension for this and it doesn't respect the default text editor styling. Does it have any additional options somewhere?

Comment: Ah, you are right. Visual Assist X was causing this, as seen [here](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W182). Thanks!